# How to check if a port is blocked on a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, port

On the Windows platform, what native options to I have to check if a port (3306, for example) on my local machine (as in `localhost`), is being blocked?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean blocked, as in blocked by a firewall or gateway, or do you mean already in use by something else?

Comment: The [Audit My PC Firewall test](http://www.auditmypc.com/firewall-test.asp) allows you to test a specific port or a range of ports from an external source.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Since you are on a Windows machine, these things can be done:

- Execute the following command and look for a ":3306" listener (you did not mention UDP/TCP). This will confirm there is something running on the port.

  **netstat -a -n**
- After this, if you are expecting incoming connections on this port and feel that the firewall may be blocking them, you could use **start windows firewall logging** and check the logs for dropped connections

  - Go to Windows Firewall, Advanced settings
  - Click on the Settings button next to "Local Area Connection"
  - Select "Log dropped packets"
  - Look at the log file location (if not present, define one)
  - Click OK
  - Now, when the connection attempt is made (assuming you know when this is done), look at the log file for a drop on port 3306.
  - If this is seen, you will want to add an exception for this port.
- There is one more command to check the firewall state
  (Updated for Windows 7 users -- as referred by `Nick` below -- use [**netsh advfirewall firewall**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709))

  **netsh firewall show state**

  - this will list the blocked ports as well as active listening ports with application associations
- This command will dump the Windows firewall configuration detail

  **netsh firewall show config**

---

If you have an active block (incoming connections are being dropped by firewall) after you start logging, you should see that in the log.

If you are running an application/service that is listening on 3306, the **firewall config** should show it to be Enabled. If this is not seen, you have probably missed adding an exception with the firewall to allow this app/service.

Finally, port 3306 is typically used for MySQL. So, I presume you are running MySQL server on this windows machine. You should therefore see a listener for 3306 accepting incoming connections. If you do not see that, you need to work with your application (MySQL) to get that started first.

Comment: Starting with Windows Vista the "netsh firewall" command is deprecated.  It recommends you use "netsh advfirewall firewall" instead and references article http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=121488

Comment: To parse output at the command line, add `|find "3306"` to the command, e.g. `C:\Windows\System32>netstat -an |find "3306"`

Comment: I can't find the settings button specified in step 2 of the second recommendation ...

Comment: @Bassie, try https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/access-protection/windows-firewall/configure-the-windows-firewall-log

Comment: @nik Thanks nik, I managd to find the checkbox, but now seeing that the log is empty after trying to access my service remotely (which always fails). I guess this just shows that the issue is not with dropped packets but must lie somewhere else

Comment: @nik - whatever link you had given Bassie, it's 404 now. Thanks Microsoft!

Answer (score 37):

Since PowerShell 4.0 you can use the command `Test-NetConnection`

If you want to test Port 3306 as in your example the command is

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName localhost -Port 3306
```

[TechNet Test-NetConnection documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn372891.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: +1 for this. A really nice alternative that doesn't require an installation of anything on most modern windows machines.

Answer (score 33):

`NETSTAT` will tell you if the port is *listening* but it will not tell you if the port is *open* to the outside world. What I mean by this is that `NETSTAT` may show that the 0.0.0.0 is LISTENING on port 3306 but a firewall may still be blocking that port which is preventing outside connections; so it isn't sufficient to rely on `NETSTAT` alone.

***The best way to check if a port is blocked is to do a port scan from the client machine.***

There are many ways to do a port scan but since you mentioned being on Windows then I will suggest the Microsoft command line utility [`PortQry`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148) and the Graphical version [PortQryUI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009)

To test all open ports:

```
portqry.exe -n #.#.#.#
```

To test a specific port:

```
portqry.exe -n #.#.#.# -e #
```

For example to test the Web interface of a router at 192.168.1.1:

```
portqry.exe -n 192.168.1.1 -e 80
```

Which returns:

```
TCP port 80 (http service): LISTENING
```

Where as testing on a local machine with no HTTPD running returns:

```
TCP port 80 (http service): NOT LISTENING
```

Using a PortScan utility you will get one of 3 results.

- `Listening` means the server is listening on the specified port
- `Filtered` means it received a TCP acknowledgement packet with the Reset flag set which likely indicates a firewall or software issue
- `Not Listening` means it didn't receive a response at all

---

`telnet` is another command line option that is usually installed on the OS by default. This command line utility can be used a quick way to see if a port responds to a network request.

To use `telnet` you would simply issue the following command from a command prompt:

```
telnet localhost 3306
```

The command above should give you a quick indication if the port `3306` on the `localhost` is responding.

Comment: I download PortQryUI and I checked after i blocked and enabled the 445 port in both tcp and udp, it is showing same listening in tcp and not listening in udp.

Answer (score 7):

If you can telnet to the port from the local machine (using the external IP address), but not from another machine - then it is being blocked somewhere between.

Note that a firewall on your local machine *could* prevent even the first action.

Comment: Note that telnet is not being installed anymore on Win7 and newer systems.

Comment: @AlexisWilke That's not correct. Telnet can be installed

Comment: To install telnet from the command line: dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient